# Why does jQuery slideToggle function stops working when window is resized?

Tags: jquery, navigation, responsive-design

I am trying to design a website with responsive design (http://eastwightendeavour.org.uk/beta), and am using jQuery to make the `nav` slide in when `#nav-btn` is clicked. This works fine when the document is loaded in either desktop, tablet or mobile mode, but not when the window is resized.

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($("#nav-btn").css("display") == "block" ){
   $("#nav-btn").click(function(){
    $("nav").stop().slideToggle();
   });
  }
});
```

How can I make my navigation appear correctly even when the window is resized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because you check the display only on page load and bind the click handler only if it is visible.

Then when you resize and media queries make it visible , the clcik handler isn't bound to it.
I don't see any need for the `if(display)` since user can't click on it when it;s hidden anyway